# Sitecore SXA - Multi-lingual Site Setup - Multi-geography

Tags: sxa, multilingual

I am working on requirement where we are setting up multiple websites hostnames in a SXA Website using various Language Versions.

Websites.

- EN-US ---- https://us.clientname.com/en

   In Site Groupings, hostname = us.clientname.com, Language = en-US, Virtual folder = /en
- EN-CA ---- EN Site -- https://ca.clientname.com/en

   In Site Groupings, hostname = ca.clientname.com, Language = en-CA, Virtual folder = /en
- FR-CA  ---- FR Site -- https://ca.clientname.com/fr

   In Site Groupings, hostname = ca.clientname.com, Language = fr-CA, Virtual folder = /fr
- ES-MX ---- https://mx.clientname.com/es

   In Site Groupings, hostname = mx.clientname.com, Language = es-MX, Virtual folder = /es

After doing the above setup, the URLs doesn't load as expected. The default Sitecore Home page under content folder [Outside Tenant, that is the default website] is being displayed.
If I remove the virtual folders, the websites work fine with appending language parameters, like

- https://us.clientname.com/en-US, https://us.clientname.com/en-CA, https://us.clientname.com/fr-CA, https://us.clientname.com/es-MX [with all three domains].

Am I doing something wrong while configuring virtual folders? Anyone please help.

To add bit more, I have only one SXA site in Sitecore CMS Tree. The items have Language Versions, en-US, en-CA, fr-CA, es-MX. The requirement is to map the URLs with respective Language Versions of the website.

Thanks

Sharad

Comment: Check this post -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009555/multi-regional-and-language-sites-sitecore

Comment: Hi @PeterProcházka, this post describes about conventional way of doing it in sitecore. However, in SXA, we do the same in Site Groupings. I am following the same and entering values as I would have given that in sites definition patch file. But this is not working. Shall I do something else via Site Groupings, or add a patch file instead.

Answer (score 0):

I also have gone through this kind of scenario, where we have some items called fr, ca, en like that. So when we add these as a virtual folder and hit the URL, the Sitecore pipelines assume it as a Language and treat this like it.

To confirm this, if you pass some phrase, that is not a language like ep or ez etc then it will work.

So to solve this we created `Custom Language Resolver`, where we added some logic by splitting the URL and then check if the phrase is not a language. And then resolved it.

The logic we used looks something like this.

```
namespace App.Foundation.LanguageResolver.Pipelines
{
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Globalization;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest;
using WCMS.Foundation.Common.Extensions;

public class CustomLanguageResolver : Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LanguageResolver
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        if (Context.Site == null
           || Context.Site.Name == "shell"
           || Context.Site.Name == "service"
           || !Context.PageMode.IsNormal
           || string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.StartPath))
        {
            return;
            
        }

        var splitUrl = args.LocalPath.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var requestedLanguage = splitUrl.NotEmpty() ? splitUrl.First() : string.Empty;

        if (requestedLanguage.Contains("healthz"))
        {
            return;
        }

        Context.Language = Language.Parse("en");
        if (this.CheckItemLanguage(this.GetItem(args.StartPath), requestedLanguage))
        {
            Context.Language = Language.Parse(requestedLanguage);
        }
    }

    public bool CheckItemLanguage(Item item, string requestedLanguage)
    {
        Sitecore.Collections.LanguageCollection collection = Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetContentLanguages(item);
        foreach (var lang in collection)
        {
            var itm = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(item.ID, lang);
            if (itm.Versions.Count > 0 && lang.Name.ToLower() == requestedLanguage.ToLower())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
    public Item GetItem(string id)
    {
        return Context.Database.GetItem(id);

    }
}
}
```

And then added this in a patch file like this.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:environment="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/environment/">
  <sitecore>
     <settings>
        <setting name="Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage" value="false" />
     </settings>
  <pipelines>
     <httpRequestBegin>
       <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LanguageResolver, Sitecore.Kernel">
         <patch:attribute name="type">App.Foundation.LanguageResolver.Pipelines.CustomLanguageResolver, WCMS.Foundation.LanguageResolver</patch:attribute>
       </processor>
     </httpRequestBegin>
  </pipelines>
 </sitecore>
</configuration>
```